# Different spacing when use subcaption package

Tags: captions, subcaption

When I use subcaption package, If set **belowskip** option, the spacing between caption with the last subcaption is big, if I do not use **belowskip** option, the spacing between subcaption with the next image is close.

Is there a way to let the system judge whether there is a subcaption above the caption, if so, disable **skip** option in the caption package, otherwise able it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={small}, justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,skip=25pt}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below,skip=0pt,belowskip=5pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}%
        \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}      
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}%
        \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}
        
        \caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text} 
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}       
        \caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text} 
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

The `belowskip` is *always* added.

I suggest to set it to zero and to add vertical space manually between rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  justification=centering
}
\captionsetup[figure]{
  position=bottom,
%  skip=25pt
}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{
  labelformat=simple,
  position=below,
  aboveskip=3pt
}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{example-image}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{example-image}}

\vspace{2ex}

\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{example-image}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{example-image}}

\caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{example-image}   
\caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text} 

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]